# Orthogonal initialization of weight matrix

Tags: neural-networks, python, orthogonal

Searching for the way to initialize the matrix weights as orthogonal (i.e. `W*W^T = I` <s>and all the [eigenvalues are equal either 1 or -1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653133/eigenvalues-in-orthogonal-matrices)),</s>(I was wrong) I found this post with a code from Lasagne:

[https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228704](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228704/how-does-one-initialize-neural-networks-as-suggested-by-saxe-et-al-using-orthogo/228716)

However, this code does not produce orthogonal, but unitary matrix with complex eigenvalues, which still satisfies equality W*W^T = I quite well:

```
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(1000)


def floatX(arr):
    """Converts data to a numpy array of dtype ``theano.config.floatX``.
    Parameters
    ----------
    arr : array_like
        The data to be converted.
    Returns
    -------
    numpy ndarray
        The input array in the ``floatX`` dtype configured for Theano.
        If `arr` is an ndarray of correct dtype, it is returned as is.
    """
    return np.asarray(arr, dtype=np.float32)

def sample(shape,gain=1.0):

        flat_shape = (shape[0], np.prod(shape[1:]))
        a = np.random.normal(0, 1, flat_shape).astype(np.float32)  #get_rng().normal(0.0, 1.0, flat_shape)
        u, _, v = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
        # pick the one with the correct shape
        q = u if u.shape == flat_shape else v
        q = q.reshape(shape)
        res = floatX(gain * q)

        #eigenvalues:
        eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eig(u)

        print(str(np.min(eigenvalues))+" "+ str(eigenvalues[1024])+ " "+ str(np.max(eigenvalues))  )

        return res 


W = sample([2048, 2048])


print(np.linalg.norm(W.dot(np.transpose(W))-np.eye(2048)))
```

The output is

`(-1+0j) (0.376566+0.92639j) (1+0j)`

for some of the eigenvalues and

`1.00117376019e-05`

for the proximity of the `W*W^T` and `I`.

1) Is this a bug in Lasagne, as `numpy.linalg.svd` indeed produces unitary matrix as it is stated in its manual, and

2) How can I initialize a (non-square) orthogonal matrix for myself in Python, except the unit one?

Thank you!

EDIT: Thanks everyone! From all the explanations I've managed to create a simple Python solution:

```
import numpy as np

## Using a subset of vectors
np.random.seed(1000)

p = 4096
A = np.random.normal(0,1,(p,p))

q, _ = np.linalg.qr(A)  # q -orthonormal

print(q.shape) #(4096,4096)

q = q[:,::2] #cut q

print(q.shape) #(4096,2048) m>n ==> q^T * q = I_n

print(np.linalg.norm(np.transpose(q).dot(q)-np.eye(2048))) # 4.26e-14
```

Comment: (2) is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/215497/how-to-create-an-arbitrary-covariance-matrix/215647#215647.  The positive/negative determinant issue is addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143903/how-to-generate-uniformly-random-orthogonal-matrices-of-positive-determinant/143970#143970

Comment: Incidentally, very few orthogonal matrices have just $\pm 1$ as eigenvalues.  Most have complex eigenvalues of unit norm.  The simplest example is the rotation matrix $$\pmatrix{\cos(t)&\sin(t)\\-\sin(t)&\cos(t)}.$$ This is all explained in the post you reference, which you appear to misinterpret--so please study it more.

Comment: @whuber Oh, I am so sorry. Somehow I also had this wrong fact in mind and just took the question from math.stackexchange as reference without checking the answers. Please excuse me for confusion.

Comment: regarding your second question, you can generate squared matrix and just remove a few columns. All vectors still will be perfectly orthogonal

Comment: @whuber Thanks very much! I've tried to replicate your code in Python:  R's procedure `qr` is equivalent to `np.linalg.qr` which produces a square orthonormal matrix `q` with high precision. I want to add that in my neural network I wish to experiment with non-square weight matrices as well, so I would be very glad to know ways to generate good quality semi-orthogonal ones.

Comment: regarding first question, method is valid and the reason why you have norm `1.00117376019e-05` is because you use 32 bit float numbers. If you use 64 bit instead, you norm would be even smaller. In my machine I got `2.0298795662912376e-13`

Comment: If by "semi-orthogonal" you mean with mutually orthogonal columns (or rows), then the SVD will do that.  An extended analysis of its properties appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139047.

Comment: btw, why do you need orthogonal weights? usually randoms are fine to start with

Comment: Thanks @whuber ! I've managed to create the code based on your point and explanations from the Aksakal's answer !

Comment: @Aksakal I'm experimenting with special activation function ([OPLU](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.02313)) which preserves orthogonality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I initialize a (non-square) orthogonal matrix for myself in
>   Python, except the unit one?

One way to make the orthogonal matrix is to get the subset of eigenvectors of any positive definite matrix.

Here's Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from numpy import linalg as LA

# create the positive definite matrix P
p = 4
A = np.random.rand(p,p)
P = (A + np.transpose(A))/2 + p*np.eye(p)

# get the subset of its eigenvectors
vals, vecs = LA.eig(P)
w = vecs[:,0:p-1]

#check that it's orthogonal 
print("matrix shape: ",w.shape)
print("check orthogonality: ",np.matmul(np.transpose(w),w))

matrix shape:  (4, 3)
check orthogonality:  [[  1.00000000e+00   3.88578059e-16  -6.21031004e-16]
 [  3.88578059e-16   1.00000000e+00   5.55111512e-16]
 [ -6.21031004e-16   5.55111512e-16   1.00000000e+00]]
```

## UPDATE

This matrix does not (and cannot) have complex elements, of course. Here's the proof:

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from numpy import linalg as LA

# create the positive definite matrix P
p = 400
A = np.random.rand(p,p)
P = (A + np.transpose(A))/2 + p*np.eye(p)

# get the subset of its eigenvectors
vals, vecs = LA.eig(P)
w = vecs[:,0:p]

#check that it's orthogonal 
print("matrix shape: ",w.shape)
print("check orthogonality: ",np.matmul(np.transpose(w),w))
print("has complex elements: ",np.max(np.iscomplex(w)))
```

Output:

```
matrix shape:  (400, 400)
check orthogonality:  [[  1.00000000e+00   1.33573708e-16   1.67509236e-16 ...,  -5.20417043e-18
    7.50267903e-17  -8.84708973e-17]
 [  1.33573708e-16   1.00000000e+00  -7.39425882e-15 ...,  -1.08940634e-15
    1.03172679e-15  -6.50521303e-16]
 [  1.67509236e-16  -7.39425882e-15   1.00000000e+00 ...,   3.15318518e-15
    1.58553726e-15   1.27155231e-15]
 ..., 
 [ -5.20417043e-18  -1.08940634e-15   3.15318518e-15 ...,   1.00000000e+00
    4.93181884e-15  -1.13573213e-13]
 [  7.50267903e-17   1.03172679e-15   1.58553726e-15 ...,   4.93181884e-15
    1.00000000e+00  -9.91155075e-13]
 [ -8.84708973e-17  -6.50521303e-16   1.27155231e-15 ...,  -1.13573213e-13
   -9.91155075e-13   1.00000000e+00]]
has complex elements:  False
```

Comment: Hmm, I took a bigger `p=40` and took a square one to begin with (`w = vecs[:,0:p]`). Then I printed eigenvalues in the same way: least, bottom and the biggest - the result I've got is `(-1+0j) (0.987257065263-0.159133551111j) (1+0j)
`. Shouldn't orthogonal matrix have only real eigenvalues all equal `-1, 1` ? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: with `p=40` square matrix `w`  has eigenvalues like `0.60580531-0.79561292j  0.46181022+0.88697876j  0.46181022-0.88697876j` which cannot be considered as floating point errors.

Comment: Please excuse me for confusion, somehow I was mistaken about the eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix and was pretty sure about it.

Comment: @Slowpoke, Orthogonal matrix can have eigenvalues as complex number. Simple example matrix: `[[0, 1], [-1, 0]]`, its eigenvalues are `[ 0.+1.j,  0.-1.j]`. Matrix 2x2 makes 90 degree rotation to any vector with real values and there is no vector with real values that mutlipling by this matrix give itself. It only exists in space with complex numbers

Comment: @Slowpoke, I'm not what's going on with your test, but this should not have complex elements by construction. I put the test code in updated answer

Comment: No, everything is fine - I was talking only about eigenvalues, not matrix elements. My test was for square w: `eigenvalues, _ = np.linalg.eig(w)` and then `print(str(np.min(eigenvalues))+" "+ str(eigenvalues[2])+ " "+ str(np.max(eigenvalues))  )`

Comment: @Slowpoke, Ok. My matrix P should not have complex eigenvalues by construction.